# How to create tree using web service?

Tags: web-services, tomcat, tree, apache-axis

I want to create tree structure using web service.
I have used bottom up web service technique for creation of simple arithmatic operation.
I can not understand, how to build a tree using web services.
Is there is way to achieve this?

Comment: Don't get it - do you need a service method that uses or returns a tree data structure and you need help on defining a suiteable xml schema for the data structure?

Comment: No.. Like for example give in this link http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/BottomUpWebService/BottomUpWebService.html They Have created a single function for conversion. Like that how should I approach to create a tree. Or my approach is wrong? I am totally confused. If this is not correct approach to create tree in web service? Is there any link or tutorial for guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recursive definition like :

```
expr = expr1 operand expr2 | node
expr1 = expr
expr2 = expr

operand = '+' | '-'

node = number
```

Then you cqn straightforward encode it using JSON or XML

15 + 3 - 2 becomes

```
{ "expr" : 
  { "expr1": { "expr1":"15" "operand":"+" "expr2":"3"} 
    "operand": "-"
    "expr2": "2"}}
```

or in xml

```
<expr>
   <expr1>
      <expr1>15</expr1>
      <operand>+</operand>
      <expr2>3</expr2>
   </expr1>
   <operand>+</operand>
   <expr2>2</expr2>
</expr>
```

In the service you can then walk the tree or build the tree. I am not sure if you see the service as a consumer or a producer.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement your web service in Groovy using Axis2, you can create a builder that produces the Axis2 [low level Axiom API](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_5_1/xmlbased-server.html) calls:

```
package example

import groovy.util.BuilderSupport  

import org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMNamespace

class OMElementBuilder extends BuilderSupport {  

    OMElement result
    String namespace

    OMElementBuilder(namespace) {
        this.namespace = namespace
    }

    def createNode(name) {
        return createNode(name, null, null)
    }

    def createNode(name, value) {
        return createNode(name, null, value)
    }

    def createNode(name, Map attributes) {
        return createNode(name, attributes, null)
    }

    def createNode(name, Map attributes, value) {
        OMFactory   fact = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory()
        OMNamespace omNs = fact.createOMNamespace(namespace, "ns")
        OMElement   node = fact.createOMElement(name, omNs)

        if (value) {
            fact.createOMText(node, value)
        }

        return node
    }

    void setParent(parent, child) {
        parent.addChild(child)
    }

    void nodeCompleted(parent, node) {
        if (!parent) {
            result = node
        }
    }
}
```

Any arbitray XML structure is then easy to create as follows:

```
package example

import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement
import javax.xml.namespace.QName

public class BankService {

    // withdraw operation
    public OMElement withdraw(OMElement requestElement) {

        // Build the response
        def builder = new OMElementBuilder("http://example")

        builder.withdrawResponse() {
            balance("1000")
            additionalInfo() {
                item() {
                    message("hello world")
                }
                item() {
                    message("hello world")
                }
                item() {
                    message("hello world")
                }
                item() {
                    message("hello world")
                }
            }
        }

        return builder.result
    }
}
```